# jQuery Datepicker - how to set: datepicker1 + 1 day becomes minDate datepicker2 with the option to switch off Saturday and Sunday

Tags: datepicker

I want to set the service selection for my clients like this:

- possibility of disabling services on Saturdays and / or Sundays (checbox - Saturday formid-1 fielid-4_1, Sunday formid-1 fieldi-4_2; by default enabled)
- minDate datapicker1 - 2 days after today (formid 1, fieldid 1)
- minDate datepicker2 - 1 day after minDate datapaicker1 (formid 1, fieldid 2)

Unfortunately, I don't have the skills. I can tell dateMin, dateMax but more complicated functions don't work.
Will someone help me? :)

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
if ( formId == 1 && fieldId == 1 ) {
    optionsObj.minDate = +2;
    optionsObj.maxDate = +33;
}
return optionsObj;
} );
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Which datepicker do you use ? What more complicated functions did you try ?

Comment: DatePicker from GravityForms